# SharePoint Hosted App error while deployment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I am working with SharePoint hosted app. So many times I Start and Run the Visual studio Solution, but last time I tried to start the solution, Error was there as below:

> 1. Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The provided App differs from another App with the same version and product ID.
> 2. Skipping the uninstall step because the app for SharePoint is in an invalid state and cannot be uninstalled.

[image: here 2 errors will display]

Please help how to solve this Error.

Answer (score 3):

Once I had the same issue. So I am glad to share my solution on this.

This type of error can occur when Uninstall is not done properly. So you might find the app solution on the server which has the GUID (i.e. - `7e45bf41-75a6-4197-816f-8a43b03f338d`).

When you try to install that app on the server it shows as the installed app on the server. I don't know why this is happening as we have already uninstalled the app.

So to overcome this error you can simply change the GUID (ID of the App feature) to the new one and then install the app. And also you need to remove the existing feature with the help of PowerShell command. Here is the MSDN article about [Remove app for SharePoint instances from a SharePoint 2013 site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/fp161233.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to deactivate the app feature.
2. You can remove the app from the site collection manually or with the powershell command. follow this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161233.aspx) and also from the Recycle bins.
3. You can Delete the app solution from App catalog and all the recycle bins i.e from  site collection and administrators Recycle bin
4. Then try to app again.

There is no need to change the Guid as this error arises mostly because the sharepoint structure is built so that it sometimes doesn't overwrite the app catalog. Even if you change the version in the appmanifest.xml file to a new version and upload the app back to app catalog this will result into an error not the same but some other.

Also Make sure to check the ULS Logs for more information. Like the permissions scenario or something else related to the Errors received.

For more information on the above mentioned procedure Please follow the links

[Link 1](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/fixing-the-provided-app-differs-from-another-app-with-the-same-version-and-product-id-error-in-office-365/)
[Link 2](http://www.mavention.com/blog/provided-App-differs-another-App-same-version-product-ID)

Answer (score 0):

Just went thru the answers above, looks like they are referring to provider hosted apps , for SharePoint apps there is no such thing as  GUID , so go to 
Appmanifest.xml

set app principle

```
 <AppPrincipal>
   <Internal/>
 </AppPrincipal>
```